# NOT using pack still getting error: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

So I know we don't mix .pack and .grid and in my simple code I haven't packed but am using .grid but still getting error.
On the bottom, I have attached the error image that I am getting along with the code
Code:

```
`from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")


# root.geometry('600x500')

def add():
    print("works")


input_num1 = Entry(root)
input_num1.pack()

button_0 = Button(root, text="0", command=add)
button_1 = Button(root, text="1", command=add)
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", command=add)
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", command=add)
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", command=add)
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", command=add)
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", command=add)
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", command=add)
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", command=add)
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", command=add)
button_add = Button(root, text="+", command=add)
button_minus = Button(root, text="-", command=add)
button_div = Button(root, text="/", command=add)
button_multi = Button(root, text="X", command=add)


button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_add.grid(row=1, column=3)
button_minus.grid(row=1, column=4)
button_div.grid(row=2, column=3)
button_multi.grid(row=2, column=4)

root.mainloop()
`
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8DYR.png)

Comment: input_num1 is using pack().

Comment: Not using `pack`? What about `input_num1.pack()`?

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been noted, you are indeed using pack().
Try commenting out the offending line (or remove it completely) and setting `input_num1` to occupy `row 4`, `column 5` in the grid, like this:

```
input_num1 = Entry(root)
#input_num1.pack()               <----------------
input_num1.grid(row=4, column=5) <----------------
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes